# How to inspect queues for a RabbitMQ that's run as a Docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

Is there a way to run `rabbitmqctl` for a Docker container of rabbitmq? I can't inspect my queues.

Also, what's so special about this command: `docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management` instead of just `docker run rabbitmq`.

Thanks.

Comment: The `-p` options make the container accessible from the host, so you can run `rabbitmqctl` as normal without doing anything Docker-specific.

Comment: When would we ever not want the container to be accessible from the host? From terminal `rabbitmqctl` doesn't work, luckily there's in the Docker desktop app an `Exec` tab and it seems to work from there, not sure if that's a good workflow.

Comment: It's very reasonable to have a set of containers that communicate amongst themselves, but only your primary user-visible HTTP endpoint to be externally accessible; you wouldn't normally want external actors messing with your RabbitMQ setup.  The `docker exec` pane is a debugging tool that I'd discourage for normal use.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same command: `docker run --net=bridge --rm -it -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management`
In the console:
[image: rabbit docker]
In the browser:
[image: rabbit browser]
Use *guest* and *guest*.